# Nginx alias ignores last letter

Tags: nginx, alias

This is getting me nervous because it does not makes sense. I want to define an alias rule, but Nginx ignores the last letter and tries to serve the wrong file for some reason.

Configuration:

```
server {
    server_name domain.com;
    listen 666;

    root /srv/http;
    autoindex on;

    location /subdir {
            alias /srv/http/someplace;
            index index.php;

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

But the error I get is `2014/05/28 17:46:25 [error] 13937#0: *221 opendir() "/srv/http/someplac" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 123.234.123.234, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "domain.com:666"`

Why isn't it reading the full path? Is there a directive like `not_ignore_last_letter` that I have to turn on?

Comment: Append '/' to path string.

Comment: @Farsheed apparently did the trick, but now it completely ignores the alias `"Unable to open primary script: /srv/http/index.php (No such file or directory)"`

Comment: Have you checked the permissions? Is PHP already installed? What about php-fpm?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [long standing (try_files & alias) bug](http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97) in Nginx.

To work around, you can use the `root` directive to set again or `SCRIPT_FILENAME` and `SCRIPT_NAME` in `fastcgi_param`.

`root` directive example

```
location /subdir {
    root /srv/http/someplace;
    index index.php;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

    # the usual stuff
}
```

Custom `$document_root` & `$fastcgi_script_name` example

```
location ~ ^/subdir /(.*)$ {
    set $custom_script_name         "/subdir/index.php";
    set $custom_document_root       "/srv/http/someplace";
    set $custom_bootstrap_script    "/index.php";
    try_files "" @customphp;
}

location @customphp {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

    include fastcgi_params;

    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME     $custom_document_root$custom_bootstrap_script;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME         $custom_script_name;

    # the usual stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to alias your php scripts path! You probably need to add something like this using fastcgi:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$
  fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
}
```